# Can not load file or assembly error in dubug but the assembly is not in any reference dirs

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

When I run my project in debug mode in Visual Studio 2013 I get the error:

> Could not load file or assembly 'ZoomASPX' or one of its dependencies

The thing is I have looked in the "References" folder and there is no entry for this assembly, I have also done a search of the entire project for "ZoomASPX" and no files contain it. How can I figure out where this assembly is being called from so I can remove it?

This project is checked into TFS and when I run the project on my desktop I do not get this error. I have checked in all changes from both the problem machine and the working machine then did a "Get Latest Recursive" on both machines but it is only broken on a single machine.

Full error screen:

> Could not load file or assembly 'ZoomASPX' or one of its dependencies.
>   An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.
>   Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.BadImageFormatException: Could not load
>   file or assembly 'ZoomASPX' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was
>   made to load a program with an incorrect format.
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the
>   current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of
>   the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>
> Assembly Load Trace: The following information can be helpful to
>   determine why the assembly 'ZoomASPX' could not be loaded.
>
> === Pre-bind state information === LOG: DisplayName = ZoomASPX  (Partial) WRN: Partial binding information was supplied for an
>   assembly: WRN: Assembly Name: ZoomASPX | Domain ID: 2 WRN: A partial
>   bind occurs when only part of the assembly display name is provided.
>   WRN: This might result in the binder loading an incorrect assembly.
>   WRN: It is recommended to provide a fully specified textual identity
>   for the assembly, WRN: that consists of the simple name, version,
>   culture, and public key token. WRN: See whitepaper
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=109270 for more information and
>   common solutions to this issue. LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/Web
>   Sites/Final Fantasy Info/FFInfo Main Site/FFInfo.WebUI/ LOG: Initial
>   PrivatePath = C:\Web Sites\Final Fantasy Info\FFInfo Main
>   Site\FFInfo.WebUI\bin Calling assembly : (Unknown).
>   === LOG: This bind starts in default load context. LOG: Using application configuration file: C:\Web Sites\Final Fantasy Info\FFInfo
>   Main Site\FFInfo.WebUI\web.config LOG: Using host configuration file:
>   C:\Users\Matthew\Documents\IISExpress\config\aspnet.config LOG: Using
>   machine configuration file from
>   C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
>   LOG: Policy not being applied to reference at this time (private,
>   custom, partial, or location-based assembly bind). LOG: Attempting
>   download of new URL
>   file:///C:/Users/Matthew/AppData/Local/Temp/Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files/root/4ec24837/6a92d301/ZoomASPX.DLL. LOG: Attempting download of
>   new URL file:///C:/Users/Matthew/AppData/Local/Temp/Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files/root/4ec24837/6a92d301/ZoomASPX/ZoomASPX.DLL. LOG: Attempting
>   download of new URL file:///C:/Web Sites/Final Fantasy Info/FFInfo
>   Main Site/FFInfo.WebUI/bin/ZoomASPX.DLL. ERR: Failed to complete setup
>   of assembly (hr = 0x8007000b). Probing terminated.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly 'ZoomASPX'
>   or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with
>   an incorrect format.]
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String
>   codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint,
>   StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean
>   throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean
>   suppressSecurityChecks) +0
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String
>   codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint,
>   StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean
>   throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean
>   suppressSecurityChecks) +34
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(AssemblyName
>   assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly reqAssembly,
>   StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean
>   throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean
>   suppressSecurityChecks) +152
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString,
>   Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr
>   pPrivHostBinder, Boolean forIntrospection) +77
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString,
>   Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean
>   forIntrospection) +16    System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(String
>   assemblyString) +28
>   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssemblyHelper(String
>   assemblyName, Boolean starDirective) +38
>
> [ConfigurationErrorsException: Could not load file or assembly
>   'ZoomASPX' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a
>   program with an incorrect format.]
>   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssemblyHelper(String
>   assemblyName, Boolean starDirective) +736
>   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAllAssembliesFromAppDomainBinDirectory()
>   +217    System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssembly(AssemblyInfo
>   ai) +130
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetReferencedAssemblies(CompilationSection
>   compConfig) +170
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetPreStartInitMethodsFromReferencedAssemblies()
>   +91    System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CallPreStartInitMethods(String
>   preStartInitListPath, Boolean& isRefAssemblyLoaded) +284
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.ExecutePreAppStart() +153
>   System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.Initialize(ApplicationManager
>   appManager, IApplicationHost appHost, IConfigMapPathFactory
>   configMapPathFactory, HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters,
>   PolicyLevel policyLevel, Exception appDomainCreationException) +516
>
> [HttpException (0x80004005): Could not load file or assembly
>   'ZoomASPX' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a
>   program with an incorrect format.]
>   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +9885060 
>   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context)
>   +101    System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest
>   wr, HttpContext context) +254

Comment: What's the stack trace?

Comment: Another component may reference it.

Comment: Grep the entire solution for that string. Include binaries. That's really primitive but it will tell you the projects and binaries that reference this component.

Comment: I added the full error screen. What really now confuses me is that this project is fully checked into TFS and I just did a full get on my desktop system and when I debug on their it works fine.

Comment: @usr What do you mean by "grep the entire solution"? Grep is a *nix command so unless your referring to something built into VS I can't run a GREP

Comment: @MatthewVerstraete find a Windows alternative like GrepWin. The tool does not matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your packages.config file if you have one.  If that doesn't work, then look in the csproj file. (edit it in notepad)

If all else fails, use agent ransack to search every file in the base directory and then remove the references that you find.

Agent Ransack (as well as some other tools) will get you the ability to search the contents of every file in a given directory.
http://www.mythicsoft.com/agentransack

Comment: I ran the program and it did not find anything. I looked in the csproj files and found nothing. This exact project works fine on another machine so I am now even more confused

Comment: Have you tried cleaning and rebuilding the solution?  What about, since the project works fine on another computer, getting a different copy from source control in a different directory and seeing if that one works.

Comment: I have done clean/builds with no change and I just unmapped the project and remapped it to a whole new DIR with a fresh get but still get the error.

Comment: Do you have the Zoom Search Engine stuff installed?  http://www.wrensoft.com/zoom/support/faq_aspdotnet.html

Comment: It has never been installed on either the working or non-working.

Comment: So I just connected my work laptop to my TFS as an experiment and on a system that has never seen the project or the Zoom program it gives the same error.

Comment: This ended up working. I did a full get and specified to over ride files even if they match the server. Then ran this program again and found an entry in hidden file, deleted the file and now everything works.

Answer (score 1):

While you have your problem solved, this error can easily occur with the Zoom search engine, which has an assembly that you can add to a solution, though it will never show up as a reference. It gets copied to your bin folder. It is a DLL of unmanaged C/C++ code of the zoom search engine with a dotnet wrapper, from what I understand.

Having said all that, there is a 32-bit and a 64-bit version of this zoom assembly. If you have the 32-bit DLL in a 64-bit project, you'll get the error message you saw. It's easily corrected by setting the "Enable 32-bit applications" setting to true in IIS for the application pool of the web application.